# Why my text wont align with avatar?

Tags: css, materialize

I am using angular-material and materializecss. I'm not really strong with css but i tried to play with it and not much of results ...
I am trying to inline the avatar with the text so far i tried to use span with class to try style the text together with img but no success..
Best result i got so far is , text after avatar but slightly below avatar.

my HTML and custom css.

```css
.gallery{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.responsive-img{
 width: 100%;
}

.img-info{
 text-align: center;
 background: #b3e5fc;
 color: black;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 10px 0;
 
}

.circle{
  width: 60;
    margin: 10px 5%;
}

.black-text{
 text-align: center;
}

.circle .black-text{
    
 display: inline;

}
```

```html
 <div class="row gallery">
  <div class="col l3 col m4 col s12"  ng-repeat="image in images"> 
  <md-card class="z-depth-3">
   
     <!--INSTAGRAM PHOTOS-->
     <a>
   <img class="responsive-img" ng-src="{{image.images.standard_resolution.url}}" alt="">
   </a>
     <!--USER AND AVATAR-->
     
    <div class="img-info">
     <img class="circle" ng-src="{{image.user.profile_picture}}">{{image.user.username}}
       
        
    </div> 
    </md-card>
   </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this:

```
.img-info img.circle{
     vertical-align: middle;
}
```

And next time, share rendered HTML, the html you was shared is not useful.

### snippet:

```css
.img-info img.circle{
     vertical-align: middle;
}

.gallery{
 margin-bottom: 10px;
}
.responsive-img{
 width: 100%;
}

.img-info{
 text-align: center;
 background: #b3e5fc;
 color: black;
 width: 100%;
 margin-bottom: 10px;
 padding: 10px 0;
 
}

.circle{
  width: 60;
    margin: 10px 5%;
}

.black-text{
 text-align: center;
}

.circle .black-text{
    
 display: inline;

}
```

```html
 <div class="row gallery">
  <div class="col l3 col m4 col s12"  ng-repeat="image in images"> 
  <md-card class="z-depth-3">
   
     <!--INSTAGRAM PHOTOS-->
     <a>
   <img class="responsive-img" ng-src="{{image.images.standard_resolution.url}}" alt="">
   </a>
     <!--USER AND AVATAR-->
     
    <div class="img-info">
     <img class="circle" src="http://dummyimage.com/50x50/000655/fff"> The text
       
        
    </div> 
    </md-card>
   </div>
  </div>
```